# Discord.js - Delete all channels

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make a bot that sets up your server and I want it to delete every channel in the server. This is my current script and its saying,

> "TypeError: message.guild.channels.forEach is not a function"

`message.guild.channels.forEach(channel => channel.delete())`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Discord JS v12. Please read [this](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html) article to see what's changed in this version.

```js
client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => { // Looping through the guilds.
    guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => { // Looping through the guild channels.
        channel.delete().catch(error => { // Deleting the channel(s) and catching any errors.
            console.log(`Couldn't delete ${channel.name}.`)
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Should mention the specific change in the code which is adding `.cache`, also in your catch statement you didn't log anything

Comment: @Karizma Thanks for the heads up! I didn't even notice. I've updated my code.